# Facebook Pixel Ajax or form with empty action

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-pixel

I am implementing facebook pixel. I follow the guide. So I have this code in the head of my page:

```
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', 'MY-ID');
    fbq('track', "PageView");
</script>
```

and I need to add this event when the form is submitted:

```
fbq('track', 'Lead', {
  content_name: 'my-Name',
  content_category: 'Valuation Form submitted',
 });
```

So normally I would add the first and second code to my 'thank you' page. But the url after submitting the form is the same as the url before submitting the form (it's either ajax or form with empty action attribute).

So I was thinking to keep the first code in the head and just execute:

```
fbq('track', 'Lead', {
content_name: 'my-Name',
content_category: 'Valuation Form submitted',
});
```

after the user submits the form and the ajax call is executed. Suggestions on this?

Comment: You know what you need to do, then what suggestion you need ?

Comment: I could not find any resources on using Facebook pixel with ajax or when there is no 'thank you page' so I thought someone could advice how it's done. Above is my best guess how I would try to do it.

Comment: You guessed it right, you can execute the last piece of code when ajax callback  is  executed